# Saving data to file in different path in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to save some data from current workspace in Matlab to a different folder. I tried using

```
 save('c:\stp\vtp\train.txt','data','-ASCII');
```

where data is a double matrix. It gives me error message

```
??? Error using ==> save
Unable to write file c:\stp\vtp\train.txt: No such file
or directory.
```

I tried using fullfile syntax, even then it is the same case. My current working folder is in different path.

Comment: Perhaps the directory does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to run `mkdir` first.  For example:

```
%Some data to save
x = 1;

%Try to save it in a deep, non-existent directory
save(fullfile(tempdir,'sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4','data.mat'),'x');  
%    This will probably recreate your error

%To fix, first create the directory
mkdir(fullfile(tempdir,'sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4'))
%Now save works
save(fullfile(tempdir,'sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4','data.mat'),'x')  %No error
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured that out. I tried to misspell the path I am trying to save in. That caused the problem.